# How do you find the equation of a quartic with 3 inflection points?

Tags: polynomials, quartics

I have 3 points where I would like inflection points. $(t0,f0),(t1,f0),(t2,f2)$

The roots give the following equation for the derivate. $y'=(x^3-(t0+t1+t2)*x^2+(t0*t1+t1*t2+t2*t0)*x-(t0*t1*t2))*g$ where g is the constant multiplied by the first 4 coefficients in case the resulting polynomial is not monic. If monic, g would be 1.

That equation results from multiplying out the following. $y'=g(x-t0)*(x-t1)*(x-t2)$

The integral gives the quartic equation with the roots at t0, t1 and t2. $y=(g/4)*x^4-(g/3)*(t0+t1+t2)*x^3+(g/2)*(t0*t1+t1*t2+t2*t0)*x^2-g*(t0*t1*t2)*x+e$

If I plug in two points, I can get g, by plugging e from one equation into the other. Then I can plug in a value to the equation to get e. I used $(t0,f0) and (t1,f1)$ to get g, and $(t0,f0)$ to get e.

I ran into some problems with this though and can not understand what is wrong.

The first problem is how do I get the equation with the third point included? When I solve the equation with the 1st two points, the third point $(t2, f2)$ isn't included. The inflection point is at t2, but f2 is wrong.

The second problem is if $t2-t1=t1-t0$ is not true, then the first inflection point $(t0,f0)$ has the wrong f0 in addition to the third point being wrong. How can that happen if the equation was derived from that point specifically?

I used the same method for cubics and two inflection points and was able to get it to work with this method, so I'm at a loss.

Is it safe to assume that the quartic can only be made from two points and a third root?

I'm sure the second problem has to do with symmetry, but I don't know why it would render the y value of the first inflection point wrong when the equation was derived from that point.

Comment: Note that note all values of $f_0, f_1, f_2$ are possible: sketch a quartic with three inflection points and (assuming you order them with $t_0<t_1<t_2$) you'll see that if $f_0 < f_1$ then $f_1 > f_2$ and vice versa. This is because for a quartic to have three distinct inflection points we must have $y''$ non-zero at the inflection points, so $y'$ must change sign.

Comment: Another way of explaining your problems is that a quartic only has 4 degrees of freedom (its coefficients) so if you know the coordinates of two of its turning points, except in special cases, there will be at most one quartic that fits!

Comment: I think I object to your use of the term “inflection point”. If you’re looking for a quartic *polynomial* in form $y=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, then it can have only two inflection points, but three local max/min. In the same way, a cubic can have only one inflection point but a local max and a local min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works right if you add a third variable and use gaussian elimination.

I used the form $y'=g*(x-t0)*(x-t1)*(x-t2)+h$. Took the integral, plugged in values for x and y, and solved for g,h, and e.